# Use a non-capturing group only in the presence of certain substrings

Tags: regex

Consider this URL for example:

`domain.com/search.action?zip=94558&year_max=2018`

I am trying to build a regex that captures domain if URL satisfies **either** of these 2 conditions

1. The URL doesn't have a `year_max` parameter.
2. The URL does have a `year_max` parameter **and** it takes one of these
   values (2019,2020,2021,2022) for year.

**Update**: The urls can have multiple `&` and could have other parameters after `year_max`. The only certainty is that `year_max` paramter is the last one that needs matching (if it exists) and all other parameters would have their capture groups defined before it.

Here is my attempt so far:

`(domain\.com)\/.*(?:&year_max=2019|2020|2021|2022)?`

How do I modify it so that if I have a set of URLs like below, it only matches on the first and the 3rd URL?

```
domain.com/search.action?zip=94558&year_max=2020
domain.com/search.action?zip=94558&year_max=2017
domain.com/search.action?zip=94558
```

[**Regex 101 Fiddle**](https://regex101.com/r/7iLVkA/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain must **not** be followed by a `year_max` that is **not** followed by 2019, 2020, 2021 or 2022.

The most intuitive translation of this double negation is the use of two [negative lookaheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(domain\.com)\/(?!.*&year_max=(?!20(?:19|2[0-2])))
```

See demo: https://regex101.com/r/D88X4n/1

Notice that lookaheads are zero-length assertions (they don't consume characters), so you could even use them along with standard capturing groups for matching other parameters.

Answer (score 1):

For the example urls with a single occurrence of `&`, you can use:

```
^(domain\.com)/[^\s&]+(?:&year_max=(?:2019|202[012]))?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(domain\.com)` Capture `domain\.com` in group 1
- `/[^\s&]+` Match `/` and 1+ occurrences of any char except `&` or a whitepace chars
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `&year_max=(?:2019|202[012])` Match `&year_max=` and either 2019 2020 2021 2022
- `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oqLZmy/1)

As you have selected Python in the regex101 tool, you don't have to escape the `/`

Comment: hmm I am starting to regret to have oversimplified the urls in the interest of keeping the question clean. The urls do have multiple & and could have other parameters after year_max.  The only certainty is that year_max paramter is the last one that needs matching (if it exists) and all other parameters would have their capture groups defined before it

Answer (score 1):

You could use a negative look-ahead for the case where the URL-query-parameter is not included:

[`^(domain\.com)\/(?:.*&year_max=(?:2019|2020|2021|2022)|(?!.*&year_max=)).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/RekQsq/1)